# Choosing a member function based on a string

Tags: c++, hashmap, function-pointers, dispatch, pointer-to-member

I have a set of hardware handler classes, all derived from a base class, which have to respond to an incoming data packet. Part of this packet is an ASCII string, which determined which member function of the hardware handler is used to process the packet (for example "fan" would execute the `ToggleFan()` function.

```
class HardwareHandler {
    virtual void dispatchCommand(const String& cmd) = 0;
}

class FooblerHandler : public HardwareHandler {

    void toogleFan();

    void dispatchCommand(const String& cmd) {
        //is this a "good" way to do this?
        if (cmd == "fan")
            toggleFan();
    }
}
```

I am using JUCE as a framework, which means I have things like templated `HashMap`s and `String`.

However, I'm having trouble coming up with a tidy way of selecting the right handler function based on this string. The construct

```
if (str == "hello")
    FooCommand();
else if (str == "bar")
    BarCommand();
```

looks pretty ugly to me conceptually as there are a lot of relatively expensive string comparisons in there. However, the code is easy to write and the logic is kept in a single place per class.

Another alternative I have tried is to make a hash-map of the strings to an enum and use that a the switch statement:

```
switch (str.getHash())
{
case CmdFoo:
    FooCommnad();
    break;
....and so on
}
```

However this also requires me to set up a static hash-map, as well as maintain the switch to match.

Something else I tried is a hash-map form the string to the member function pointer itself, hoping to be able to jump directly from the string to the member function without having list them in a case statement, and also allows a very generic dispatch function, as it just needs to look up in the hash-map, it doesn't even need to know all the options - they can be contained solely in the hash-map, allowing me to maybe push the dispatch function into the base handler class and not repeat myself in each specific device handler. However, this method has stumped me as I can't quite work out how to do it correctly, or even if it is possible to do this with a static hash-map and member-functions.

Is there an idiomatic way to dispatch to member functions based on a string (or similar hard-to-compare type), preferably with as much logic able to be genericised and moved to the parent class as possible?

Comment: How about `std::map<std::string, std::function<...> >`?

Comment: Do all of your methods return `void`?

Comment: No, they return `bool` in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try. You can encapsulate the mapping mechanism into a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

class X;

template<class X>
class handler_factory;

template<>
class handler_factory<X>
{
private:
    using HandlerType = void (X::*)();
public:
    handler_factory();

    HandlerType get(const std::string& name) const
    {
        if (handlers.find(name) == handlers.end())
            return nullptr;
        else
            return (*handlers.find(name)).second;
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, HandlerType> handlers;
};

class X
{
public:
    friend class handler_factory<X>;
private:
    void f();
    void h();
};

handler_factory<X>::handler_factory()
{
    handlers["f"] = &X::f;
    handlers["h"] = &X::h;
}

void X::f() { std::cout << "X::f();"; }
void X::h() { std::cout << "X::h();"; }
```

And your dispatch method can be implemented as:

```
void dispatch_method(const std::string& name)
{
    if (find_handler(name))
        (this->*find_handler(name))();
}

int main()
{
    X().dispatch_method("f");
}
```

Where `find_handler` is defined as a private helper method:

```
private:
    auto find_handler(const std::string& name)
        -> decltype(handler_factory<X>().get(name))
    {
        return handler_factory<X>().get(name);
    }
```

Comment: Does `handler_factory` have to be specialised for every subclass of `HardwareHandler` (e.g. `FooblerHandler`, `BarrifierHandler`, etc)?

Comment: @Inductiveload Yes, but this is only for convenience. Different classes may have different member function signatures. If they don't, `handler_factory` does not need to templatized but can just be a regular class.

Comment: @Inductiveload Scratch that: Actually, you do not. If `Bar` is a class that inherits from `Foo`, and `X` is a class that is specialized for `Foo`, `X<Bar>` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to deal with the problem is creating a `std::map` that would map your strings into appropriate functions. The method is fast (due to the logarithmic searching algorithm), easy and safe.

```
class FooblerHandler : public HardwareHandler {
   typedef void (HardwareHandler::*function)();
   map<string,function> commandMap;

   void dispatchCommand(const string& cmd) {
      if(commandMap.count(cmd))
         (this->*commandMap.find(cmd)->second)();
      else
         cout << "No command found with name \"" <<cmd<< "\"." << endl;
   }
};
```

And of course you should init the map inside the constructor (or somewhere before using it):

```
commandMap["fan"] = &FooblerHandler::toogleFan;
commandMap["someOtherCommand"] = &FooblerHandler::otherFunction;
```

[Maps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and included in the Standard Template Library (STL) which nearly all IDE's supply.

**EDIT:**
I didn't quite read the text at the end. Well - now you know the syntax :)